# Разница в днях между двумя датами

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Как высчитать разницу дат в днях?
Например, между сегодняшней датой  `datetime.datetime.today()` и любой другой?

```
import datetime

class knigi():
    def __init__(self, kniga, name, god):
        """создание книги"""
        self.y1 = datetime.date.today()
        self.kniga = kniga
        self.name = name
        self.god = god

    def gody(self):
        print(self.y1.year - self.god.year)

    def days(self):
        print(self.y1.day - self.god.day)
```

Логично, что мне выдает разницу лишь в днях, не учитывая месяц и год, а писать формулу я не могу, ибо есть високосные годы...

Думаю, есть более легкий способ?

Comment: может это натолкнёт вас на решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115002/234134

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime
    
some_date = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
now_date = datetime.now()
```

Даты можно вычитать:

```py
>>> a = some_date - now_date
>>> print(a)
-33 days, 8:46:31.530036
```

Результатом разницы `some_date` и `now_date` будет объект типа `timedelta`, у которого есть метод `days`, им и воспользуйтесь:

```py
>>> print(a.days)
-33
```

Comment: только лучше использовать `date`, а не `data` в названиях переменных в данном контексте.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```py
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.today()
d2 = datetime.timedelta(days=30, minutes=3)

print(d1-d2)
```