# Счетчик сколько прошло времени с даты telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу сделать чтобы в моем боте по команде показывало сколько лет,месяцев, дней, прошло с даты 14.12.2020 но не знаю как сделать, искал код в интернете не нашел

Comment: datetime.timedelta

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115002/234134